# How to create a CNN for image classification with dynamic input

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I would like to create a fully convolution network for binary image classification in pytorch that can take dynamic input image sizes, but I don't quite understand conceptually the idea behind changing the final layer from a fully connected layer to a convolution layer. [Here](https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-conversion-of-last-layers-of-CNN-from-fully-connected-to-fully-convolutional-allow-it-to-process-images-of-different-size) and [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12830/how-are-1x1-convolutions-the-same-as-a-fully-connected-layer)  both state that this is possible by using a 1x1 convolution.

Suppose I have a 16x16x1 image as input to the CNN. After several convolutions, the output is a 16x16x32. If using a fully connected layer, I can produce a single value output by creating 16*16*32 weights and feeding it to a single neuron. What I don't understand is how you would get a single value output by applying a 1x1 convolution. Wouldn't you end up with 16x16x1 output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link: http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#convert

In this case, your convolution layer should be a 16 x 16 filter with 1 output channel. This will convert the 16 x 16 x 32 input into a single output.

Sample code to test:

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Input
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
input = Input((16,16,32))
output = Conv2D(1, 16)(input)
model = Model(input, output)
print(model.summary()) # check the output shape
output = model.predict(np.zeros((1, 16, 16, 32))) # check on sample data
print(f'output is {np.squeeze(output)}')
```

This approach of Fully convolutional networks are useful in segmentation tasks using patch based approaches since you can speed up prediction(inference) by feeding a bigger portion of the image.

For classification tasks, you usually have a fc layer at the end. In that case, a layer like AdaptiveAvgPool2d is used which ensures the fc layer sees a constant input feature size irrespective of the input image size.
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#adaptiveavgpool2d

See this pull request for torchvision VGG: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/pull/747

In case of Keras, GlobalAveragePooling2D. See the example, "Fine-tune InceptionV3 on a new set of classes".
https://keras.io/applications/

Comment: Does this mean I cannot train a CNN for binary classification without knowing the input image size since I would need that information to set the kernal size?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are familier with keras. Now see your image is of 16*16*1. Image will pass to the keras convoloutional layer but first we have to create the model. like `model=Sequential()` by this we are able to get keras model instance. now we will give our convoloutional layer with our parameters like

```
model.add(Conv2D(20,(2,2),padding="same"))
```

now here we are adding 20 filters to our image. and our image becomes 16*16*20 now for more best features we add more conv layers like

```
model.add(Conv2D(32,(2,2),padding="same"))
```

now we add 32 filters to your image after this your image will be size of 16*16*32

dont forgot to put activation after conv layers. If you are new than you should study about activations, Optimization and loss of the network. these are the basic part of neural Networks.

Now its time to move towards fully connected layer. First we need to flatten our image because fully connected layer only works on 2d vectors (no_of_ex,image_dim) in your case
imgae diminsion after applying flattening will be (16*16*32)

```
model.add(Flatten())
```

after flatening our image your network will give it to fully connected layers

```
    model.add(Dense(32))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(Dense(8))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(Dense(2))
```

because you are having a problem of binary classification if you have to classify 3 classes than last layer will have 3 neuron if you have to classify 10 examples than your last dense layer willh have 10 neuron.

```
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=Adam(),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
   return model
```

after this you have to fit this model.

```
estimator=model()
estimator.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

full code:

```
def model (classes):
    model=Sequential()

        # conv2d set  =====> Conv2d====>relu=====>MaxPooling
    model.add(Conv2D(20,(5,5),padding="same"))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(32,(5,5),padding="same"))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(32))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(Dense(8))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(Dense(2))

        #now adding Softmax Classifer because we want to classify 10 class

    model.add(Dense(classes))
    model.add(Activation("softmax"))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

[You can take help from this kernal](https://www.kaggle.com/sohaibanwaar1203/cifar-10-keras-hyperparameters-settings)